# 'x' and 'y' lengths differ in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a horizontal line in R, but it is giving me an error.

Code:

```
w <- seq(1, 99, by=1)
alpha <- 0.1
beta <- 0.001

U <- alpha*w -(beta/2)*w*w
Uprime <- alpha -(beta)*w
Udprime <- -beta
Utprime <- 0

plot(w,Udprime,type = "l",main = "Graph of U(W) versus wealth",xlab = "Wealth",ylab = "Utility Function")
```

When I plot this function out, I get this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Why is that so? Need some guidance.

Comment: Because `length(w)==99` and `length(Udprime)==1`? I assume you meant `plot(w, Uprime, ...)` instead.

Comment: ok thanks, how to solve that problem?

Comment: Udprime is the second derivative with respect to `w`, which is constant for all values of `w`. So a plot would show a horizontal line. What is it that you're trying to actually plot?

Comment: Maybe you want `plot(w, U)` ?

Comment: Or set `Udprime <- -beta + 0 * w` so that it's length is the same as `length(w)`.

Comment: If you really want to plot a horizontal line, wouldn't it be easier to just use `abline`?

Comment: @joran How would do that?

Comment: `abline(intercept, slope)`, so `abline(-.001, 0)` in your case

Comment: @SeñorO There are also `h` and `v` arguments to specify horizontal and vertical lines directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot the horizontal line for the second derivative of the wealth utility function, you'll need to make sure `Udprime` has a point for every point `w`. There's two ways to do this:

Shortcut:

```
plot(cbind(w, Udprime))
```

More "true to the math":

```
Udprime = -beta * w^0
```